# Return all values for the title JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently is displaying only one title I would like all of the titles printed.

```
$.getJSON("http://...", function (data) {
    $(".make-text").html(data.query.results.channel.item[0].title);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22Ecw/63/)

Comment: Print how? Comma separated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22Ecw/64/)

You need to iterate over the items.

```
$.getJSON("...", function (data) {
    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
        return item.title;
    });
    $(".make-text").html(titles.join('<br>'));
});
```

Map is often used to extract a property of objects in an array.

Comment: Ah! Beat me to it. This is exactly what I'd do. +1